# Changing the request URL in woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code and it function perfectly but I still don't have my result that I require here is the code:

```
<label><?php _e('Tag'); ?></label>
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
    <div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', // Taxonomy to return. Valid values are 'category', 'post_tag' or any registered taxonomy.
            'show_option_none' => 'Select Tag',
            'show_count' => 0,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'value_field' => 'slug',
            'echo' => 0
        );
        $select = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
        $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
        echo $select;
        ?>
        <noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the code and it gives me the cat for example it gives me

> url.com/?cat=tag_slug

I need to have

> url.com/?product_tag=tag_slug

can someone help me pls :(

Comment: The dumbest (but working) solution is to do `$select = str_replace("?cat=", "?product_tag=", $select);` before echoing, but something else would be far better (see `name` attribute and set it to `product_tag`): https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Comment: I tried it but it does not work :(

Comment: `str_replace(...)` must work, without any doubts. Nevertheless, it is not the right way: did you read the documentation? Did you set in `$args` the key-value pair `'name' => 'product_tag'`?

Comment: thank you very much it worked..

can you put both your comment as answer so I can give you the credit that you deserve 
thank you again

Comment: Awesome! I merged both comments in an answer, thank you very much

Comment: Little reminder to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dumbest (but working) solution is to do:
`$select = str_replace("?cat=", "?product_tag=", $select);` before echoing.

Something else would be far better (see `name` attribute and set it to `product_tag`): https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories

Set in `$args` the key-value pair `'name' => 'product_tag'`